# IBM MQ acknowledgment timeout query

Tags: ibm-mq

appreciate if someone can clarify below question on IBM MQ v9:

If two applications (could be multiple instances of same application running on cloud) are listening to same queue ( i.e. competing consumer pattern) and using auto_acknowledge mode, and if APP1 receives a message M1 but doesn't acknowledge the message for say 15 min (it's taking long time to process), would MQ deliver same message M1 to APP2?

In other words, does MQ has a limit to how long it would wait for ack before deciding that the APP1 has probably died and message should be redelivered to next APP2?

I have tested this on a local setup (start two consumers, Thread T1 receives message M1 and sleeps for 1h, monitor other thread T2 - it doesn't get same message). While this gives me some assurance but I have seen case in my production env of two threads eventually getting same message, not sure if it one off case or something I am missing.

note: The app listens to a queue using Spring framework DefaultMessageListenerContainer @JmsListener .

Comment: If usng auto_acknowledge mode, application can't explicitly acknowledge, MQ JMS library will automatically acknowledge after delivering message to application. Application can explicitly acknowledge is using Client Acknowledge mode.

Comment: MQ queue manager periodically checks health of application connections and will rollback any transactions if it detects a client application has gone away without comitting.